# Entity Framework include child items with filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am currently working with a schema which contains entities, each containing attributes and each of them contain one type specification. I want extract a list which fulfills a specific attribute requirement it being of the type lookup and a specific specification.

I have tried this so far

```
schemaRepository
                .Many()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Entities
                    .Where(x => x.Attributes
                        .Any(y => y.Type == DataType.Lookup &&
                                  y.TypeSpecification.EntityInternalName == "Weather")));
```

This returns a list of entities which fulfills the requirement, but none of the entities has any attributes?

How do I also include this within the query?

I tried adding include at the end,

```
var entitiesWithLookupsTolookupEntityName = schemaRepository
            .Many()
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
            .Include(x=> x.Entities)
            .ThenInclude(x=>x.Attributes)
            .ThenInclude(x=>x.TypeSpecification)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Entities
                .Where(x => x.Attributes
                    .Any(y => y.Type == DataType.Lookup &&
                              y.TypeSpecification.EntityInternalName == "Weather")));
```

but this just include all attributes and etc. ignoring the Any condition for the attributes..

How to get around this?

I tried splitting it a bit

```
        var entitiesWithLookupsTolookupEntityName = schemaRepository
            .Many()
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
            .Take(1)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Entities
                .Where(y => y.Attributes
                    .Any(z => z.Type == DataType.Lookup && z.AttributeTypeSpecification.EntityInternalName == lookupEntityName))).AsEnumerable();

        IList<ReferenceView> output =  new List<ReferenceView>();

        foreach (var entity in entitiesWithLookupsTolookupEntityName)
        {
            var attribute = schemaRepository.Many().OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).First().Entities
                .Where(x => x.InternalName == entity.InternalName);

        }
```

but here I get an exception every in for loop

Comment: Will this work? https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-include-filter

Comment: Unfortunately i guess it would -  I was looking for a more EF only solution rather than involving third party libraries.  @scor4er

Comment: EF Core does not support filtering navigation properties. You could query just the `Attributes` and not keep the `Entities`, etc., or query them as separate objects (not using `Include`) and let relationship fixup connect them or you could wait for [the feature to be released](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1833), or possibly (and tricky to get right) use a global query filter.

Comment: I get an exception that a command is already in progress... @NetMage

Comment: @kafka Doing what?

Comment: @NetMage I updated it the post